# Laravel 10 jetstream does not display the Manage Account menu when logging in to production, when I am developing it works perfectly

Tags: laravel

Laravel 10 does not display the Manage Account menu when logging in to production, when I am developing it works perfectly.

[Developing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRLW2.png)
[In production](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIHNb.png)

Hice npm run dev, para subir a mi servidor cpanel

This is the url of the page in production
https://hogardeancianossanagustin.com/

I already tried clearing the cache, and redoing the project, but it's the same error, although I can't call it an error since it doesn't show me any errors.

Comment: HAve you run npm install

Comment: @TobyAllen Yes I did, but it didn't work either, I think it's a problem with jetstream.

Answer (score 0):

To clear the compiled view files, run the following command from the terminal, they are not cleared together with the other caches

```php
php artisan view:clear
```

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for taking your time and responding, I did that and the message "INFO Compiled views cleared successfully." But nothing else happened, the menu is still not displayed, unfortunately.

Comment: could you show me your view?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a problem with jetstream, because I created the same project with breeze and it worked perfectly, thank you very much for your answers.

In case anyone has the same problem, I suggest using breeze.